# Windows 10 - Windows won't wake from Sleep S3 if connected through HDMI to the TV

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, sleep, wake-up

I have a new PC with Windows 10 which I would like to be connected with HDMI to the TV. But if so, the screen does not wakeup after Sleep, I have to turn the PC off with the Power button and turn it on again. However, if it is connected through VGA (the PC has to video outputs: VGA and HDMI), the screen turns it on smoothly. Drivers are updated (with manufacturer package and Driver Booster also) and Windows update is also up to date. I tried it on three monitors/TV with three different HDMI cables with the same result. I've looked everywhere and cannot find the solution. When in S3 USB ports have no energy so they cannot wake the PC up but this is OK, I can use Wake on LAN. Things I have tried after searching the Internet:

- Look in the BIOS, only options are Sleep in S3 mode and Hibernation. If I disable S3 it will work, but of course it will not Sleep either which is not an option.
- In the Power Plan advanced I have:
  o   Unchecked all Allow the Computer to turn off this device and Checked all Allow this device to wake the computer
  o   Set up Required a Password on wakeup as NO.
  o   Removed Hibernation
- I have tried HdmiON which I saw in this web with Task Scheduler or with a program called Hibernate Trigger. After this test, I can say that HdmiON is not launched at all, so my conclusion is that the PC is not awaken when connected through HDMI. It is like the PC wouldn’t wake up because an external monitor is not detected, is this possible?
- In the BIOS I have changed the main video output to PCIe
- Manufacturer provided latest Drivers and BIOS.

Right now I have the PC connected to the TV through VGA and HDMI at the same time with Clone Displays. With this remedy the PC would wake up and I could use HDMI as video output. But this is not the desired solution since I cannot configure the highest Resolution in this scenario and maybe the PC is consuming more power than it should. Also tried with Extended monitors and HDMI as the Main one and didn’t work.

Does anyone know a Solution? Manufacturer would not give one if it is Driver or BIOS related, so my only hope is some Remedy better than the one I have currently.

Many thanks for your help in advance!